# Подсветка кода с помощью Prettify

Tags: javascript, jquery

Библиотека `prettify` от google почему-то отказывается нормально подсвечивать языки. Как ее правильно подключать? Я подключаю так: `prettyPrint();` в событии `document.ready` и класс `prettyprint` у тега `pre`. В итоге, такой код:

```
REM ----- method teardown
PRINT "green"
RETURN
IF af=0 THEN GOTO 520
FOR j=1 TO af
ac=pf(j) : me$=STR$(j)+". factor" : GOSUB 100
NEXT
RETURN
DATA "one", 1, 0
```

не распознается. Такие слова как `PRINT`, `RETURN`, `FOR` - должны выделяться, а они не выделены...

Comment: Какой язык в вашем листинге? Входит ли он в список поддерживаемых?

Comment: Здесь `basic`, в архиве есть `lang-basic.js`.

Comment: В консоли ошибок нет?

Comment: Нет. Но вроде разобрался, там надо нестандартные языки подключать как скрипты к шаблону.